# Page-wide figure with sidecaption in two column article

Tags: floats, two-column, width, article, sidecap

Having some trouble getting my latex document to format this properly. I know there's difficulty using floats in two column documents, but there's got to be a way to make this work properly. I'd like to have an (almost) page-width figure placed on the bottom of a page that is two-column formatted for text, while also being able to place the caption on the side of the figure.

I've tried a variety of packages including `sidecap`, `dblfloatfix`, and `stfloats`, and I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just can't figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Example:

[image]

Here's my MnWE. Had to create a dummy document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,superscriptaddress,floatfix,longbibliography]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
\usepackage{bm} % bold math font
\usepackage{graphicx} % for figures
\usepackage{comment} % allows block comments
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{titling}

% \usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont \bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont \itshape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,topsep=1pt,parsep=0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\label{sec:introduction}Introduction}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{figure*}[b!]
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}
    \label{fig:cat}
\end{figure*}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{SCfigure*}[b!]
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat cat}
    \label{fig:cat}
\end{SCfigure*}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) or in your case an MnWE.

Comment: You have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done. Use the `figure*` environment instead of `figure` to get a fullwidth figure on a twocolumn page.

Comment: Edited with MnWE. I know that ```figure*``` makes fullwidth figures, but doesn't seem to work when using ```SCfigure*```. It still places the side-capped figure in one of the two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for figures
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\lipsum
\begin{SCfigure*}[0.25] % <---
\begin{wide}            % <--- defined in "sidecap" package
     \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{fig:cat}
\end{wide}
\end{SCfigure*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! I'd tried ```wide``` before but I kept getting errors, realize I'd never defined the width and that's why I was getting errors. A workaround I was using was to create a figure with two minipages, one containing the caption and the other containing the figure, but this is much more concise and works better with ```hyperref```.

Comment: As a followup, is there an easy way to bottom align an ```SCfigure*```? ```b``` and ```b!``` don't seem to work very well.

Comment: @latexuality,  to have figure over two column on the same page where is inserted (if there is enough space for it) you need to load package `stfloats`.

Comment: Even with ```stfloats```, the ```SCfigure*``` seems to be forced top-align on the page when using ```b``` or ```b!```

Comment: @latexuality, than there is no way to do this. Sorry, I newer test this.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help!

Comment: The default size limit for bottom floats is much smaller than top floats (0.3\textheight vs. 0.7\textheight).  See macros \dbltopfraction and \dblbottomfraction.